# Do contiguous monolayer aromatic structures retain the same magnetic susceptibility as the core constituents?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, materials, aromaticity, magnetism

As the synthesis of Porphyrin monolayer strips is achievable, retaining the core aromaticity of the tetrapyrrole; does it still retain the same value of magnetic susceptibility of porphyrin? Does this apply to other systems like these?